# Retrieving MS Word Document from Database and Saving Locally

Tags: linq-to-sql, dialog, save-as

I have used AsyncFileUpload AJAX control to upload a file to a column in a SQL Server database using LINQ to SQL.  How do I retrieve the document from the database and allow the user to save to local drive using a Save As Dialog box using LINQ to SQL?  This is ASP.NET web application.  The DocumentFileContent database column is a Image SQL Server data type.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way in webforms is to use an HTTP handler.

The DB query for an `image` datatype will map to a `byte[]`.

```
public class Document : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT imagefield FROM table", con);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(reader["imagefield"]);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```